# Adding a blurred border in CSS

Tags: css, image

Using CSS,  how can I add a border of 100px to all sides of an image that is made up of the perimeter pixels stretched out and blurred? e.g. the border to the left of the image is just columns 1-3 stretched horizontally and blurred together?

I see other posts explaining how to keep the edges sharp but blur the center.

Comment: Look for shadow, not for border.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/blurred-borders-in-css/

Answer (score 39):

If you want to blur an image to the edges ***and*** if you have one single `background-color` then you could use the `box-shadow` with `inset` to archive your desired behavior:

```
box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 40px 40px #DBA632;
```

where `#DBA632` is your background-color.

See this snippet:

```css
body {
  background: #DBA632;
}
div {
  background: url('https://picsum.photos/500/300');
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 50px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 40px 40px #DBA632; /* change to alter the effect*/
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

---

Old answer:

Are you looking for something like this?

```
box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 40px #000000;
```

The first two values set the offset of the shadow, the third value is the amount of blur and the last value is the spread of the shadow.

You can play with those values to see how they change the effect: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/q0c3a39f/)

Comment: I'm looking for a blur from an image, looks like box shadow is just a single color?

Comment: @OneSolitaryNoob you should write that clear in your question not just in the comments!

Comment: sorry wavemaster,  that's what I meant by taking the perimeter pixels and stretching them out

Answer (score 7):

`box-shadow` is what you want.  I put some links below that will teach you everything you need to know about it:

http://www.css3.info/preview/box-shadow/

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-shadow.asp

Comment: is there a way to make a shadow based on an image?    not a single color

Comment: Sorry, I never saw your question here.  I guess it's been a while, but I thought I would still give you an answer:  The only way I can think of to do that would be to use CSS3 filters (see this link: http://www.inserthtml.com/2012/06/css-filters/).  I would try using the blur filter and position it behind the object that you want it to be a shadow of (by giving it a lower z-index), and offset it a little bit.  Combine that with the brightness filters to darken it.  That's all I can think of, but I've never tried it myself.  Good luck.